# grep a list into a multi columns file and get fully matching lines

Tags: bash, grep

not sure how to ask this question but an example would surely clarify. Suppose I have this file:

```
$ cat intoThat 
a   b
a   h
a   l
a   m
b   c
b   d
b   m
c   b
c   d
c   f
c   g
c   p
d   h
d   f
d   p
```

and this list:

```
cat grepThis 
a
b
c
d
```

now I would like to **grepThis** **intoThat** and I would do this:

```
$grep -wf grepThis intoThat
```

which will give an output like this:

```
**a b**
a   h
a   l
a   m
**b c**
**b d**
b   m
**c b**
**c d**
c   f
c   g
c   p
d   h
d   f
d   p
```

now the asterisks are used to highlight those lines that I would like grep to return. These are the lines that have a **full match** but...how to tell grep (or awk or whatever) to get only these lines? 
*Of course it is possible that some lines do not match any pattern, e.g. in the intoThat file I may have some other letters like g, h, l, s, t, etc...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`, you could do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ seen[$0]++; next } ($1 in seen && $2 in seen)' grepThis intoThat
a   b
b   c
b   d
c   b
c   d
```

- `NR` is set to 1 when the first record read by *awk* and incrementing for each next records reading either in single or multiple input files until all records/line read.
- `FNR` is set to 1 when the first record read by *awk* and incrementing for each next records reading in current file and reset back to 1 for the next input file if multiple input files.
- so `NR == FNR` is always a true condition for first input file and the block followed by this will perform actions on the first file only.
- The `seen` is an associated `awk` array named `seen` (you can use different name as you want) with the key of whole line `$0` and value with occurrences of each line occurred (*this way usually is using to remove duplicated records in `awk` too*).
- The `next` token skips to executing rest of the commands and those will only execute actually for next file(s) except first.
- In next `(....)`, we are just checking if both column$1 and $2 are present in the array, if so they will goes in output.

Comment: Right approach ++ but it should be: `$1 in seen && $2 in seen`

Comment: it works but...can you give a little details about how it actually works? I can understand (if I'm right) that `$1` and `$2` refers to the two columns of intoThat and probably `in seen` means that the pattern was found somewhere...but what about the remaining code?